# How can I cite Google Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory, citations

**Hello everyone!**

I am currently using Colabs for some Python analyses (I am usually using R, so Colabs was a quick solution). I want to cite Colabs in my method section of my article but couldn't find any bibliographical information or how to cite it. Has anyone cited Colabs recently and could help me out here?

**Thanks a lot!**

**What have I done so far?** I had a look on their website and FAQ, wrote them a message, looked for articles on stack overflow...

Comment: Use the website citation format of your article publisher. It is out of the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks! But I actually don't mean the citation format but bibliographical information (like version number, etc.) :)